# Pushing events to observable from arbitrary sources

Tags: rxjs

I have a root UI component that has an Observable `pageTitle`. The child components will update this value, meaning emit new page titles.

What are some elegant ways of achieving this many-to-one push scheme?

Comment: Probably using an instance of `Subject` but it's hard to give a better advice from this very brief description :).

Comment: @martin I felt that since this is a very general question, a very brief description was appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am using at the moment is a [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/Subject-spec.js.html#lineNumber8), like martin suggested. The "arbitrary" event emitters, as phrased in the question, call its `.next(val)` method to push a new value.